# Acceptance test in paypal

Tags: paypal, yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm checking the payment (Acceptance test) on my local site via PAYPAL using codeception:

```
    ...
    $I->wait(20);
    $I->fillField('#email', Yii::$app->params['paypalSandBoxEmail']);
    $I->fillField('#password', Yii::$app->params['paypalSandBoxPassword']);
    $I->click('#btnLogin');
    ...
```

[paypal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwbJj.png)

I got the exception during runinig the test:

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidElementStateException] invalid
>   element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be
>   manipulated
>
> ...$I->fillField("#email","test@test.com")...

In html _output directory and at the screenshot the elements are visible and available.

Can codeception manipulate elements on not local websites?

Output `run acceptance -vvv`

> [Selenium browser Logs]
>   14:38:47.986 WARNING -
>   sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC%2d10383446M95501121
>   - The SSL certificate used to load resources from sandbox.paypal.com will be distrusted in M70. Once
>   distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See
>   g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>   14:38:48.416 WARNING -
>   sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC%2d10383446M95501121
>   - The SSL certificate used to load resources from paypalobjects.com will be distrusted in M70. Once
>   distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See
>   g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>   14:39:10.132 WARNING -
>   sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC%2d10383446M95501121#/checkout/login
>   - The SSL certificate used to load resources from t.paypal.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented
>   from loading these resources. See g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts
>   for more information.
>   14:39:10.132 SEVERE -
>   sandbox.paypal.com/signin/inject/?stsRedirectUri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandbox.paypal.com%2Fcheckoutnow%2F2&country.x=DE&locale.x=de_DE&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandbox.paypal.com%2Fcheckoutnow%2F2&state=%3Fflow%3D1-P%26token%3DEC-10383446M95501121&flowId=EC-10383446M95501121&correlationId=5ef92280bac18&flowContextData=-HJ-BNZU5rCkFqyKDprAzbm4EgEmAIblp_XBfaD8Mdq-ts7mu_sA8ecAFFcGW3WF_dAAVGD4V90uyvqKKStxAsUOAtr_u2oqqkb1v-6GJHgw4OfxwuH0RTx4MYK&rememberMe=true
>   - Failed to load paypalobjects.com/auth/createchallenge/9225440d84fd667e/challenge.js:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Comment: the domain on which you load your site shouldn't matter, all manipulation happens in client-side via your webdriver. please run your test with verbose (-vvv) and post it's output

Comment: @csminb I updated the post.